# don't initialize variable if isset returns false

Tags: php, codeigniter, isset

I have a simple statement like this:

```
$data['title']  =   isset($domain['title']) ? $domain['title'] : '';
```

This is ok. The data array is then used in an insert query using codeigniter active record. Now I wanted to ask is there a way that if isset returns false, then don't initialize $data['title'].

I know the alternative here

```
if(isset($domain['title'])){
   $data['title'] = $domain['title'];
}
```

I want to know how can we do the same `if` with the upper instruction?

Comment: This is a poor case for using ternary.  Any solution that allows you to execute this expression in ternary is going to be unclear and confusing code at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, but use `if` is more readable.

```
isset($domain['title']) && ($data['title'] = $domain['title']);
```

Edit:
Example of using a loop.

```
foreach (array('title', 'body', 'footer') as $key) {
  if (isset($domain[$key])) {
   $data[$key] = $domain[$key];
  }
}
```

Comment: but if i have 7 or 8  fields will i use 7 or 8 if s?? i need simple i line of code to handle. neat and clean

Comment: @raheelshan You could use a loop.

Comment: can you give an example of loop

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way I can see to do this is:

```
if (isset($domain['title'])) $data['title'] = $domain['title'];
```

But stick with your second example, it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

well you can do:

```
$data['title'] = !isset($domain['title'] ? : $domain['title'];
```

In php 5.3 or later.

But I wouldn't recommend it as it is ugly confusing code.